# Why does Flask + SocketIO + Gevent give me SSL EOF errors?

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, flask, gevent, flask-socketio

This is a simple code snippet that consistently repeats the issue I'm having. I'm using Python 2.7.12, Flask 0.11, Flask-SocketIO 2.7.1, and gevent 1.1.2. I understand that this is probably an issue better brought up to the responsible package's mailing list, but I can't figure out which one is responsible. However, I'm pretty sure it is a problem with gevent because that's what raises the exception.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import ssl

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect_event():
    print('Client connected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8443,
                 certfile='ssl/server/server.cer', keyfile='ssl/server/server.key',
                 ca_certs='ssl/server/ca.cer', cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

And here is the error I get when the client connects:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 534, in 
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 25, in
    return handle(*args_tuple)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 126, in wr
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_sslgte279.py", line 691, i
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_sslgte279.py", line 271, i
    raise x

    SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
    <Greenlet at 0x7fdd593c94b0: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method WSGInd method WSGIServer.do_close of <WSGIServer a, (<socket at 0x7fdd590f4410 SSLEOFError
```

My system also has OpenSSL version 1.0.2.j if that helps. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: This was reported to me before (see https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/88), but never found what was the issue. It is quite possible that this is a gevent related bug. You may be able to bypass this if you have a proxy server that you can configure to terminate your SSL, as the person in the bug reported I linked did.

Answer (score 0):

Use patch_all on top of the code. Even before flask and socketio import.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

import ssl
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to help.